# How can I make Windows 10 remember the desktop assignment of different chrome windows

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Every time I close Chrome, Restart Win10 or log out and log in and start Chrome, all of my tabs and windows pop up in one place and I have to put them back onto the desktop they were on originally. How can I set the application to do this automatically?

Comment: If the window is closed normally, it will appear in the closed position the next time it is opened. If the window is closed abnormally, it will not appear in its original position the next time it is opened. What kind of situation did you encounter? Maybe you can provide some screenshots.

Comment: I'll clarify in the original post.